# properly replace a cv::Mat with an own-ROI (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to crop a `cv::Mat` - that is, not simply have it point to a ROI of a broader metrix in memory, but really get rid of all the original data but those in the ROI. More, I need my interface to be consistent with the opencv tradition of not-returning mats; essentially I want this:

```
void crop(cv::Mat& source, cv::Rect roi, cv::Mat& destination);
```

(but since in my case source===destination) it could be simply this:

```
void crop(cv::Mat& mat, cv::Rect roi);
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
void crop(cv::Mat& original, cv::Rect roi) {
  cv::Mat roi_in_original {original(roi)};
  cv::Mat new_mat;
  roi_in_original.copyTo(new_mat);
  original = new_mat;
}
```

which is not only verbose but probably sub-optimal. S would IT be plausible to directly copy the ROI to the original mat:

```
void crop(cv::Mat& original, cv::Rect roi) {
  cv::Mat roi_in_original {original(roi)};
  roi_in_original.copyTo(original);
}
```

would that be OK??

Comment: What about "dst = src(roi).clone();" or "mat = mat(roi).clone();"?

Comment: `mat = mat(roi).clone()` looks elegant and tempting.. will try it out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll change your first version to:

```
void crop(const Mat& src, const Rect& roi, Mat& dst)
{
    dst = src(roi).clone();
}
```

where the input arguments are `const`. You can save the result in the same matrix calling:

```
Mat m = ...
Rect roi = ...    

crop(m, roi, m);
```

I'll change your second version to:

```
void crop( Mat& m, const Rect& roi)
{
    m = m(roi).clone();
}
```

that you can use like:

```
Mat m = ...
Rect roi = ...    

crop(m, roi);
```

Note that the call to `clone()` is needed in both cases to make the resulting matrix *continuous*, as you would expect.

---

I personally prefer the first variant, since it's more general. However, you can also avoid in the first place a function for cropping, since it's just as easy as:

```
Mat m = ...
Rect roi = ...

m = m(roi).clone(); 

// Or, to save to a different matrix
//Mat n = m(roi).clone();
```